# Custom SQL query in JPA repositories

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

For the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT fd FROM DPPFile fd WHERE fd.ID= ':ID'")
List<DPPFile> findByID(@Param("ID")String ID/);
```

I'm getting the following weird exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
```

I'd expect this exception if I was using ?1 instead of the named parameter approach. Using the ?1 fails as well so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.
The DPPFile class has a member called ID as well as getter/setter.

(The reason I'm not using the default "findByID" with no query on top of it function is because I want to extend the query with additional parameters)

Comment: why are you putting a parameter in single quotes? That will mean it is interpreted as a STRING ':ID'

Comment: Aaargh! That was it. Pfff, I've been looking into this issue for an hour and it was in front of my eyes the whole time. Thanks, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the parameter in single quotes otherwise it is resolved as a literal. Hence the query will not be registered.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can skip the whole `@Query` annotation by using spring-data `findOne` assuming `ID` is your unique identifier in the entity. Otherwise, you can rely on spring-data to generate the query from the name of the method. Use something like this:

```
@Entity
public class DPPFile {

  @Id
  private Integer identifier;

  private Integer ID;
}

public interface DPPFileRepository extends Repository< DPPFile, Integer> {

   List<DPPFile> findByID(String ID);
}
```

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation